# How to define a list of: variables1,variables2, variablesN

Tags: c, variables

I want to do the following:

```
#define ConfigureCAN(index,value) CAN.MBOX##index=value
 for (i=0;i<15;i++) ConfigureCAN (i,0);
```

This doesn't work. Is there an other way then:

```
 ConfigureCAN  (0,0);
 ConfigureCAN  (1,0);
```

...

Thanks.

Edit: Wil this work Or better is the indexing of the stuct correct?
#define ConfigureCAN(index,value) {struct MBOX *Mailbox;Mailbox = &can.MBOX0 + (index * sizeof(struct MBOX)); MBOX=value;}

Comment: `This doesn't work` what does that mean?

Comment: BOOST_PP_REPEAT instead of for-loop

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use a `for` loop index variable (which only gets its value at run-time) to build a compile-time symbol name like that. The symbol names are not available when the program runs, i.e. when the `for` loop executes, so it doesn't make any sense.

You can probably set up a (pointer) array to make accesses easier to loop, but then you're going to have initialize the array which will be similiar-looking (but enable better run-time performance, if that's your goal).

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do so in C.

Depending on the framework and hardware you use, there might be an alternative way to address your CAN structs:

- If you need the `MBOX###` values more often in a loop, you can create an array with pointers at an appropriate place:

  volatile int * MBOXPOINTERS[] = { &CAN.MBOX0, &CAN.MBOX1, /* go on on your own */ };

  (replace `volatile int` by whatever is used in the respective header file)
- If you have the device data sheet and you see that the fields are in a successive way, you mght eveb ne able to define an array situated at the appropriate address. But that is highly hardware dependent.